# JQuery Empty Function

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to completely empty a div, I have it populated on load with PHP and a foreach loop, its printing programs from a database, here's what the source looks like when the page is first loaded

```
<div class="frame" id="program_list">                                       
<div class="box">
    <div class="box-holder">
        <div class="box-frame">
            <h3>Marathon</h3>                       <p>Run 26 miles around the city.</p>                                            <p>Trainer: John Doe</p>
                                                <span class="btn-program"><a href="#" tabindex="10"><em>BID PROGRAM</em></a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                    <div class="box">
                                        <div class="box-holder">
                                            <div class="box-frame">
                                                <h3>Jumping Jacks</h3>
                                                <p>Do 400 Jumping Jacks in 15 minutes</p>
                                                <p>Trainer: Jane Doe</p>
                                                <span class="btn-program"><a href="#" tabindex="10"><em>BID PROGRAM</em></a></span>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

And I'm trying to empty the program_list div with a jquery empty function like this:

```
        function clear_programs_div()
    {
        alert("Test");
        $("program_list").empty();
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to get rid of the div's. Does this function only remove inner text and not  elements? How come its not removing any of the elements inside? Any advice would help thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you need to add a `#` before program_list

```
$("#program_list").empty()
```

Comment: @Pete Herbert Penito, your welcome, I would appreciate if you accept my solution.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery id selector needs # before actual id. 
If you want to select elements by css class you add . before class name.

```
$("#program_list").empty()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$("div#program_list").remove();
```

`remove()` will remove the div with id 'program_list' **and** everything contained within.

`empty()` will remove the content within the div **but** not the div element itself

[see jQuery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but I wanted to keep the div, and just remove its contents :)

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery if you want to access an element with id you must use `#`.

For example:  `$("#program_list").empty()` or `$("#program_list").delete()`

However if you want to access an element with class you must use `.`

For example:  `$(".program_list").empty()` or `$(".program_list").delete()`

**With `$("#program_list").empty()` would completely empty your div**